# arithmetic overflow in codility test

Tags: c++, algorithm

I did the codility demo test "NumberOfDiscIntersections":
https://codility.com/programmers/lessons/4

I've got: perf = 100% and correctness 87%

All tests but one went fine:

```
overflow 
arithmetic overflow tests
```

Why was my long long, not enough ? I can't figure what went wrong!

```
#include <algorithm>


int solution(const vector<int> &A) 
{
    // write your code in C++11
    vector<long long > vec_max;
    for(int i = 0; i < A.size(); ++i)
    {
        vec_max.push_back( A[i] + i );
    }
    std::sort(vec_max.begin(),vec_max.end()); // sort by max

    int step = 1;
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i = A.size() - 1; i > -1; --i)
    {
        std::vector<long long>::iterator low;

        int nb_upper = A.size() - ( lower_bound( vec_max.begin(),vec_max.end(), (long long) (i - A[i]) ) - vec_max.begin() );
        counter += nb_upper - step;
        ++step;
    }

    if (counter > 10000000)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        return counter;
    }
}
```

Comment: You still have some `int` variables. Are you sure none of them will overflow?

Comment: Alternative for looping downwards: `for(auto i=A.size(); i!=0;) { --i; ...}` and consider the comment of @n-m.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the A array is very large, you might end up adding large indices to the counter `int` variable. The `step` variable is quite small compared to it

```
counter += nb_upper - step;
```

and this is likely where you're overflowing a variable.

Comment: Yes, "max of counter" is that every disc intersects every disc, I did not think of it but with 100.000 discs this is roughly = 1 +2 + .. + 100.000 ~ (N^2+N) / 2 ~ 5.000.050.000 which is indeed overflow. I got screwed often by my lack of extreme tests, this is one thing codility teaches me :)

Comment: Yes, if you have a natural numbers sum as input data use Gauss' formula to estimate the complexity (in big-O that would be n^2 bounded) and see that for a 32 bit integer you only need to reach n = 46340. I assume this is way higher since you wrote 100k